# Loopj - Uploading Files with RequestParams c# .net

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, loopj

Trying to upload a file with params using loopj. 
im trying to get file from Request.Files and params from Request.Form["create"]
but it is not uploading to the server.

Android Post method

```
try { 
                String createTeamURL = "http://url"; 
                RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                params.put("file", new File(pathoffile));
                params.add("create", regString);
                AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                client.post(createTeamURL, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onStart() {
                        // called before request is started
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
                        // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
                        // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
                        // called when request is retried
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("createTeamPreStep", e.getMessage());
            }
```

My Web Api c# method

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<string> CreateUHS()
        {
            var resultString = "";

            foreach(HttpPostedFileBase s in Request.Files)
            {
                var a=s; 
            }

            String sdf = Request.Form["create"];

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use put for string args.
please find the below both server and client methods.
and one more thing im really worried about your naming variable. its bad. please change it.  Happy coding.

```
    String createTeamURL = "http://url"; 
            RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
            params.put("file", new File(pathoffile));
            params.put("create", regString);
```

Server (Web api)

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<string> CreateUHS()
        {
            var file=Request.Files[0];
            String otherArg = Request.Form["create"];
        }
```